# MySql Insert returns null

Tags: php, mysql, json

i have the following function:

```
public function insertMomentToDB($uid, $type, $data)
{

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO moments_newsfeed(user_id, type, time, data) VALUES(?, ?, NOW(), ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $uid, $type , $data);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();


    // check for successful store
    if ($result) 
    {
        return true;
    } 
    else 
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

where $data = json undecoded, i want to put it in json format inside the table

$result is always null so it returns false..

Comment: You are using PDO, correct? And this function is in a class that defines `$this->conn` in the constructor?

Comment: set it up so if there is an error in the insert it shows an error message

Comment: Just a note @wogsland, PDO doesn't have `bind_param`, mysqli does. In PDO it's `bindParam`.

Comment: if error reporting in php were turned on, you would not have to ask this question...

Comment: Tip: `return !!$result` forces it to a boolean.

Comment: Do you have MySQL 5.7 with support for the [`JSON` column type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html)?